# Why is the optimized fibonacci with cache described as top-down solution?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

It seems that an optimized version of fibonacci algorithm is using memoization.
Example:

```
int cache[N] = {0};  

int fibonacci(int n) {  
  if(cache[n] != 0) return cache[n];    
  if(n ==1 || n == 2) cache[n] = 1;  
  else cache[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);  
  return cache[n];  
}
```

This is described as a top-down solution.
But why? To find `fibonacci(10)` we need to recursively call all the lower numbers until we reach to 1 and start building up. So it seems to me it is a bottom-up approach.
Why is it top-bottom?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't formal definitions for what it means for an approach to be top-down or bottom-up, but generally a top-down approach is one where you start with a larger problem, subdivide it into smaller pieces, and combine the solutions to the smaller problems into the solution to the original problem. A bottom-up solution is one where you start with solutions to small problems and progressively step up the size until you have a solution to the overall problem.

The function you have above uses memoization. Since the function is recursive, it exhibits the typical top-down pattern of starting with a larger problem, splitting it into pieces, and combining them. And, since the function caches its results and that cache gets populated in a way that starts with smaller terms and progressively grows to larger terms, the cache seems to function bottom-up.

I haven't heard the term "top-bottom" before, but I've seen many other algorithms like this one that exhibit some top-down structure combined with a bottom-up approach. LR parsing is a great example of this - it works bottom-up, using an understanding of the ultimate top-down structure as a guide.

Comment: `A bottom-up solution is one where you start with solutions to small problems and progressively step up the size until you have a solution to the overall problem.`. This is how I see the process in the post. We have to go all the way down to `fibonacci(1)` and `fibonacci(2)` and solve them and start adding up. Somehow I am confused in getting this

Comment: While that’s true, consider the sequence of recursive calls made. They begin large and progressively shrink down to smaller and smaller sizes.

Comment: So what makes it top-down is that the starting point is e.g. `fibonacci(100)` instead of `fibonacci(1)`?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It might help to rewrite the code bottom-up to see the contrast.

Answer (score 0):

It is top bottom because if that you already have computed all the other numbers, you rely on them. 
The target is at the top, and you use the other computations as the bottom

Comment: If I call `fibonacci(100)` then nothing has been calculated and is calculated bottom up. If I call after that `fibonacci(10)` then it is constant time since it has been already calculated. So I still don't get why it is top-down

Comment: yes but look at templates in C++. You can do it from 100 then 99, etc...